# Angular $injector modulerr error on injecting ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing, angularjs-ng-route

When I include ngRoute for routing I get this error $injector MOdulerr, Kindly let me know what am I doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Below are my two files, index.html and app.js

```
<head>   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-aria.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src='app.js'></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css"> 
</head>
```

**app.js**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp',['ngRoute'])
myapp.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    $routeProvider
        .when('/sign-in', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/sign-in.html',
            controller: 'appctrl'

    })
})

myapp.controller('appctrl', function ($scope) {

});
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error? nothing wrong the above code

Comment: seems to working fine i created a plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/HXjk2GyGT4q2cJidqW6t?p=preview

Comment: only thing i did was change the `http` to `https` since plnkr support secure calls

Comment: when I click on the error it takes me to a page on angularjs.org site, the link is too long to be posted here, this is what that page says                                                       Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp

Comment: This is exact error 
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.1%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332

Comment: are you sure you're using the correct cdn?

Comment: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-route.js" is what the angular docs has

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: If failed to instantiate `myApp` because the code defines it as `myapp` with no capital letters.